# php base64 decode image

Tags: php, base64, symfony4

Использую Symfiny 4, получаю uploaded files `$files = $request->files->get('file');`

в `$files` содержится массив с картинками, закодированными в base64: `"data:image/png;base64,iVBO..."`, сами строки валидные

при использовании любой функции работы со строками, например при `explode(",", $base64string)` получаю массив с 1 эелментом `"/tmp/phpc373bO"`

Кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: Насколько я понял $files у вас объект типа файл. Чтобы получить его содержимое в строку попробуйте. $contents = file_get_contents($files->getPathname());

Comment: @coder675, спасибо за ответ, нет $files представляет собой массив строк

`$files[0] == "data:image/png;base64,iVBO..."
$files[N] == "data:image/png;base64,...";`